# Adding fields to category manager. Does a method exist to get the link to the category edit screen?

Tags: plugin-development

This code is working fine, just want to make sure I'm ok with hardcoding the href to the category edit screen with...

```
"edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=category&post_type=post&tag_ID='.$cat_id.'"
```

Or is there a method I should call to get the category edit link dynamically (in case the call ever gets changed)?

```
//add the filter in order to add custom columns to the category manager 
add_filter('manage_category_custom_column', 'display_cat_columns', 10, 3);

//This function outputs the custom category image onto each row of the category manager grid.
function display_cat_columns($arg1, $column_name, $cat_id){
  if ('ce4_cat_image' == $column_name) {
  return '<a href="edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=category&post_type=post&tag_ID='.$cat_id.'">get_category_thumbnail_admin($cat_id, 'thumbnail').'</a>';}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function which is used internally (since 3.1) is `get_edit_term_link( $term_id, $taxonomy, $object_type = '' )`. Source view [here](http://wpseek.com/source/wp/latest/nav.html?wp-includes/link-template.php.source.html#l679).

There's also a function called `edit_term_link` that will format the link output for you.

The built-in functions are probably better to use, because they check for user capabilities, etc., and are better for future compatability.  That said, I think you're safe using the hardcoded url for backwards compatability. I don't know how it was done in previous versions, and I think those links might have been hardcoded like you're doing...

**Edit:** I was curious what was done before that function was introduced, so I looked through the source. Prior to 3.1, `get_edit_tag_link( $tag_id, $taxonomy = 'post_tag' )` did the same thing - now it's just rewritten to use `get_edit_term_link` internally. So if you want to support all recent versions of WordPress, use this function:

```
//add the filter in order to add custom columns to the category manager 
add_filter('manage_category_custom_column', 'display_cat_columns', 10, 3);

//This function outputs the custom category image onto each row of the category manager grid.
function display_cat_columns($arg1, $column_name, $cat_id){
  if ('ce4_cat_image' == $column_name) {
      if (function_exists ('edit_term_link'))
        return edit_term_link( get_category_thumbnail_admin($cat_id, 'thumbnail'),
                '', '', $cat_id, false );
      else return '<a href="'.get_edit_tag_link($cat_id, 'category').'">'.
                get_category_thumbnail_admin($cat_id, 'thumbnail').'</a>';
  }
}
```